# 000webhost.com Custom Error page does not work?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, error-handling

When i change the code and add something new it doesnt even lets me load my normal page. If delete the `ErrorDocument 404/error.php`(and the others) I can normally enter my site.

Here is my sites domain: [carnageband.tk](http://carnageband.tk)

Here is the code:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

What should i do to bypass the page which it redirects me? [LINK](http://error404.000webhost.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and the issue seemed to be coming from the .htacess file. The webpage would load okay again after I deleted the .htaccess file.

I was able to fix it by editing the .htaccess file from the cPanel, File Manager instead of transferring the file over FTP, but I'm not really sure why it wasn't working before.

My code looks similar to yours:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 403 /errors.php?p=403
ErrorDocument 404 /errors.php?p=404
ErrorDocument 500 /errors.php?p=500
```